# Tests fail with 'mvn test' on grails project converted from 2.2.4 to 2.4.3

Tags: unit-testing, maven, grails

I have successfully converted two projects from grails 2.2.4 to 2.4.3.  I can run the tests, and run-app both from the grails command line, and within ggts.

Then, I converted it to a maven project, by using create-pom to get an initial pom.xml file.  After getting the dependencies right, I can again run the tests and the app from the command line and ggts.  But I am getting errors on my unit tests (not spock tests) using 'mvn test'.

The errors look like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at grails.test.runtime.GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.createParentContext(GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.groovy:143)
    at grails.test.runtime.GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.initGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.groovy:96)
    at grails.test.runtime.GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.onTestEvent(GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.groovy:327)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.deliverEvent(TestRuntime.groovy:295)
```

It feels like some kind of setup , or dependency issue.

Comment: Do you have `pom true` added in `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: I tried it with and without 'pom true' - same error.  If I understand correctly, 'pom true' tells grails commands to use the pom for dependency, but maven commands already use the pom, so it doesn't matter to maven.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Can you add `pom.xml` to question?